# Weird nested-if statement execution

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have this interesting problem with some code I wrote in Java. I am executing this code in  in the latest version of eclipse with jdk-17.0.1. The purpose of the code is to take a screenshot of my screen every couple of milliseconds, but only if running is true. At the start, running is false. I can set running to be true by hitting a certain key. Here is the code

```
        double timePerTick = 1_000_000_000/fps;
        double delta = 0;
        long now;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (true) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+= (now-lastTime)/timePerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                //for some reason code only works if this print statement here
                //System.out.println("WOWEE");
                if (running) {
                    //Create rectangle screen-capture around cursor
                    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0, width, height));
                    try {
                        output.write(("Capture taken \n").getBytes());
                        System.out.println("WRITTEN!");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("BRUH!");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                delta--;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the if (running) statement never runs, even when running is true. However, when I uncomment the System.out.println statement after the if(delta) code, it works perfectly well. Like this:

```
        double timePerTick = 1_000_000_000/fps;
        double delta = 0;
        long now;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (true) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+= (now-lastTime)/timePerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                //for some reason code only works if this print statement here
                System.out.println("WOWEE");
                if (running) {
                    //Create rectangle screen-capture around cursor
                    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0, width, height));
                    try {
                        output.write(("Capture taken \n").getBytes());
                        System.out.println("WRITTEN!");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("BRUH!");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                delta--;
            }
        }
```

In the first code, nothing gets printed, but in the second code, WOWEE gets printed over and over again. By the way, if running is true at the start, then both codes work fine. However, if you switch from running = false to running = true, the first code never prints anything, but the second code goes from printing nothing to printing WOWEE. Is there any reason for this?

By the way, output is a FileOutputStream instance if that is necessary info.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure if print statement is the only statement this occurs for. I tried using int x = 0, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you share the running declaration?

Comment: @tcgumus boolean running = false

Comment: @user16320675 I don't know what volatile means, so I'm not sure

Comment: @user16320675 Thanks, it works. If you post that as an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: @user16320675 I don't use multiple threads, though, so I don't get why the error shows up

Comment: I thought you need volatile if you are using multi threads. Which part of the code using it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @user16320675 Oh wait, you're right, it's running on a thread that tracks keyboard input

Comment: @user16320675 I am using the system-hook library

Comment: https://github.com/kristian/system-hook

Comment: Yea, thank you I learned something new today :) @user16320675

Comment: @user16320675 I did, it works perfectly, check my comment in reply to yours

Comment: @user16320675 My thank you comment above that "Thanks, it works. If you post that as an answer, I'd accept it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user16320675 found the answer to my problem in the comments, but for some reason they deleted their comments. I waited to see if they'd come back, but they didn't. So, I will post the information they gave me. The reason my program didn't work is because the variable "running" was being accessed by multiple threads, one thread being the main thread, and the other thread being the one that monitors keyboard input. When a piece of memory is being accessed by multiple threads, you must declare it as "volatile" to make sure synchronization issues don't happen. Like this

```
public static volatile boolean running;
```

More information here https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile

Comment: Yes. Another option that doesn't require `volatile` is using `AtomicBoolean` which is a thread safe class, but `volatile boolean` works too.